# Change realm file without restarting app

Tags: realm

I'm using realm with iCloud document, so question:

How can I change realm file without restarting app when iCloud document changes?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "change Realm file"? Do you mean the file on the disk where the Realm database is stored? If so, it's not recommended to move it while the app is running.

Comment: Thanks. But as I said, I am trying to sync realm file with iCloud, so the file could be changed when the app is running.

Answer (score 4):

You should never change a Realm file while it is opened by a Realm object. This could end in unknown side effects.

So I would recommend to export the realm file whenever it makes sense. This file could be synced via iCloud and also be monitored for changes - to import the changes.

Exporting method explained the docs: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm15writeCopyToPathFS0_FTSS13encryptionKeyGSqCSo6NSData__GSqCSo7NSError_

If the realm file is larger there is another disadvantage: iCloud would always sync the whole file even for smaller changes.

In short: It feels complicated to implement a clean, conflict free syncing solution using Realm and iCloud. Maybe you should think about using CloudKit or any similar backend service to realize your data syncing:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm trying to use CloudKit.